# Getting the latest entries for every group

Tags: sql, django, sqlite, django-orm

I am trying to build a simple storage example in django 4.0 where stuff is inserted to a storage table defined like this:

```
class material_storage(models.Model):
      storage_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
      material = models.ForeignKey(itemtype, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
      amount = models.IntegerField(null=True)
      price = models.FloatField(null=True)
      timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

To retrieve the latest entry for every material within this table I need something looking like this in SQL:

```
SELECT material_id, amount, price, MAX(timestamp)
FROM assetmanager_material_storage
GROUP BY material_id
```

Since I'm new to Django, I haven't managed to recreate this query yet. I found some threads suggesting solutions like:

```
material_storage.objects.values('material').annotate(latest_record=Max('timestamp'))
```

but that's not working in my case, instead throwing an error "name 'Max' not defined". The other approach would be to go like this:

```
material_storage.objects.all().latest('timestamp')
```

but this would only return the latest object in the whole table and I couldn't figure out for now how to apply "latest" on every material instead of all records. So I am kinda stuck now. If somebody could tell me what I'm missing, I would be grateful.

thx in advance.

Comment: `Max` is an aggregation function that has to be imported first https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#max
Add `from django.db.models import Max` in the top section of your file where import other packages and modules.

Comment: Thank you for that one, it solves the problem with 'Max'. The problem with this approach in general is that it returns a list of values, not a list of objects like for example objects.all() does. I solved it for now by just pushing raw SQL but thats no too satisfying considering there is an ORM available. Any idea how to solve that?